# Maven Site Plugin with Java9

Tags: java, maven, travis-ci, java-9, maven-site-plugin

I have a problem running my CI builds on Travis with Java9 (Oracle JDK 9).

I fails on `maven-site-plugin` - after removing it everything works smothly.

I tried removing everything else to check for possible dependencies collisions, left out with just this one plugin build still fails. It is just a pom container, still failing with just a simple site plugin (updated to latest version that claimed to be java9 ready).

Here are all of the resources:

- [failing Travis build](https://travis-ci.org/chilloutdevelopment/pl.chilldev.parent/builds/294946250)
- [Travis configuration](https://github.com/chilloutdevelopment/pl.chilldev.parent/blob/feature/ci-fix/.travis.yml#L74)
- [project POM file](https://github.com/chilloutdevelopment/pl.chilldev.parent/blob/feature/ci-fix/pom.xml)

Looking for similar problems on the web I found that usually it's plugin compatibility (all of the plugins ware updated) or different dependencies versions, but I removed all of them and it still fails.

The builds run locally on OpenJDK 9 perfectly fine.

-edit-

After applying hint from @nullpointer :

- [updated POM](https://github.com/chilloutdevelopment/pl.chilldev.parent/blob/db3c48e2da9e664ab5fcc19394575cc040b79623/pom.xml#L118)
- [CI error](https://travis-ci.org/chilloutdevelopment/pl.chilldev.parent/builds/294966927#L1032)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably wait and update to using version `3.7` of site plugin as mentioned [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Java+9+-+Jigsaw).

Seems like you are encountering something similar to ***[#MSITE-796](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSITE-796)***

Quoting further from the same link:-

> The release will need a little bit more time due to pending
>   `SNAPSHOT`-dependencies which need to be released first. So either have
>   a little bit more patience or add `doxia-sitetools` `1.7.5` as a dependency
>   to the maven-site-plugin in your own project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
    <artifactId>doxia-sitetools</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

-edit-

As `doxia-sitetools` is just a `pom` container project one needs to update all of it's modules directly:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
                        <artifactId>doxia-decoration-model</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.5</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
                        <artifactId>doxia-skin-model</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.5</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
                        <artifactId>doxia-integration-tools</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.5</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
                        <artifactId>doxia-site-renderer</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.5</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
                        <artifactId>doxia-doc-renderer</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Nice tip, however doing just this doesn't work - `doxia-sitetools` is `pom` package - https://travis-ci.org/chilloutdevelopment/pl.chilldev.parent/builds/294966927#L1027 (including dependency with `<type>pom</type>` doesn't affect transitive dependencies). Is there any way to achieve this, or I need to type all Doxia components manually?

Comment: @RafałWrzeszcz Please share the updated pom components in the question. Though the error seems strange. Did you try specifying the dependency as in under `<depedencies>` tag or within plugin dependency?

Comment: As a plugin dependency. Finally made it working! Updated your answer to contain working final snippet. That was long (according to Git history ;P).

Comment: @RafałWrzeszcz Just to know, doing so in pom.xml of project's direct `<dependencies>` with just `doxia-sitetools` 1.7.5 didn't work?

Comment: Nope. https://travis-ci.org/chilloutdevelopment/pl.chilldev.parent/builds/294977863#L472

If I got this one right this is totally expected - project dependencies participate in artifacts building, not a build-time environment, which is run-time of plugins.